# SQLITE Query is breaking while using single inverted comma with the string

Tags: android

My Select query is breaking of single inverted comma in the where clause string like  (select * from  where Col_Name in(?),new String []{list});

and list ="'abc','tyur','iop','nj'd','sjc'jskj'";

please let me know if there is any workaround for the above-mentioned issue.

Comment: 'nj'd'     may be issue is here

Comment: Ya, I know this is the problem and for the same, i need a workaround because this type of string i am getting dynamically so I want to handle it through code end , do you have any idea

Comment: UPDATE ITEM_TABLE SET Strike_SW=? WHERE Item_name in ('fg'ggg','xhhd','gddh','hxjd') AND List_Name =  ?) how to handle this error?

Comment: did you try replace

Comment: `db.rawQuery("select * from Some_Table where Col_Name in(?,?,?,?,?)", new String [] {"abc", "tyur", "iop", "nj'd", "sjc'jskj"})`

Comment: but my IN clause not has fixed arguments, it may vary so it will not work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the ' character before passing it in the query.

**Replace ' with ''(two single quotes)** in your string.

Here is a simple string sanitizer for sql queries.

```
 public static String sanitizeSqlString(String text) {
return text !=null ? text.replace("\'", "\'\'")
    .replace("\"", "\"\"")
    .replace("`", "``")
    .replace("\\", "\\\\") : text;
```

}

You need to sanitize each element by iterating through the list.

Comment: @sonu i have added a string sanitizer, try using it. This will sanitize your string for common special characters.